# SyntaxError: Unexpected token . when releasing project in GitLab repository to Heroku

Tags: heroku, gitlab

I'm trying to deploy my project from GitLab repository to Heroku, and on the last stage, release app, throwing this SyntaxError. I tried reinstall Heroku using different methods including brew and NPM. Also looked into the command.js file in

```
/usr/local/lib/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/command.js
```

which contain this code, `delete this.globalFlags?.json;` but I don't have any clue so far. All the apps and tools are most updated version.

Followings are the error message on GitLab deploy.

```
/usr/local/lib/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/command.js:41
            delete this.globalFlags?.json;
                                    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/index.js:6:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

Comment: Check the Node version you're using against https://node.green/#ES2020-features-optional-chaining-operator-----

Comment: @johrsharpe, I'm new to this field, so it would be nice if you elaborate how this chart would be helpful for my issue because just looking at this website made me more confused..I suspected my issue is something to do with node version or node module and tried couple things some suggested from other questions but don't have clue so far..

Comment: _"I suspected my issue is something to do with node version "_ - and that's also what I'm suggesting, that site shows language features by Node version, and yet you haven't included what it currently is. Give a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I updated image: node:10.17-alpine to image: node:14-alpine on my gitlab-ci.yml and my app successfully deployed!